# how i can rewrite my URL http://www.ritascantina.com/latestnews/index/18 to http://www.ritascantina.com/latestnews/18

Tags: php, html

i want to reqrite my URL.

existing url is : `http://www.ritascantina.com/latestnews/index/18`

and i want like this: `http://www.ritascantina.com/latestnews/18`

My HTACCESS FILE IS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(home(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What are you getting when you try and access the page?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you arent matching the digits at the end so that rule isnt getting used. Try changing:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?(\d*)$ $1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

This way you will get the numbers at the end as well

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
RewriteRule ^latestnews/([0-9]+)/?$   latestnews/index/$1
```

Refer [this document for examples](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).